# Understanding a Proof for Cyclic Groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

Here is the theorem:

[image]

Here is the proof:

[image]

I underlined in red the parts I did not understand. For the first one, why is it $0\leq i-j<1$? For the second one, why is $0\leq r\leq n-1$ significant? Sorry, my professor wrote this proof a year ago and I am trying to fully grasp what they were trying to say, since I am still a beginner...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part: you know that there is no positive integer $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^n=e$. Actually, this also implies that there is no non-zero integer $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^n=e$ (do you see why?). But you find out that if $a^i=a^j$ for some integers $i,j$, then $a^{i-j}=e$. According to the above, the only possibility of this occuring is when $i-j=0$, that is $i=j$.

For the second part: take any integer $k$ and look at the element $a^k$. Actually, the value of this element only depends on the congruence class of $k$ modulo $n$ (the order of $a$). In other words, let me write down the Euclidean division of $k$ by $n$: $k=nq+r$, with $q,r$ two integers such that $0\leq r < n$. Then, we have $$a^k=a^{nq+r}=(a^{n})^qa^r=e^qa^r=a^r$$
But $r\in \{0,1,\ldots ,n-1\}$. So $a^k\in \{a^0=e,a^1=a,a^2,\ldots ,a^{n-1}\}$. This shows that any element of the form $a^k$ (eg for $k$ equal $7$ or $k$ equal $-1000000000$ or any other integer you like) can be computed as $a^r$, for some small $r$ just between $0$ and $n-1$. It simplifies things a lot! The sequence of powers of $a$ only takes, periodically, a finite number of values (exactly $n$ distinct values).

Comment: @Bernard Absolutely! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for taking the time to explain and reply. I have been wondering about the implication that $n$ cannot be non-zero. Is it due to inverses? Or the fact that having a negative $i$ or $j$ can produce a positive difference $i-j$?

Comment: @numericalorange If there were some negative integer $n$ such that $a^n=e$, then taking the inverse, we obtain $a^{-n}=e$, which comes in contradiction with the hypothesis that $a$ has infinite order.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one,  since there is no *natural* number with $a^n=e$, the fact that $a^{i-j}=e\implies i-j$ isn't a natural number.   On the other hand $i-j$ is a whole number.   The only whole number that isn't natural is $0$...

For the second part,  $0\le r\le n-1$, by the division algorithm.  Also, there is a typo.  It should say:  Let $a^k\color{red}{\in} \langle a\rangle$...