# Understanding a Cyclic Group Proof

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

For one of my [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874375/understanding-a-proof-for-cyclic-groups/2874395#2874395), the following answer was given by [Suzet](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/562979/suzet):

[image]

The thing is: I do not see why... Is it because of inverses or because having a negative could make $i-j$ positive? I asked this in the comment but no one replied yet. Does anyone know? :) I feel like I am missing something very trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variant: $\enspace$if $a^{-n}=e\;(n\in\mathbf N)$, then $\; e=e^{-1}=(a^{-n})^{-1}=a^{(-n)(-1)}=a^n.$

Comment: Very simple answer and super easy to understand! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that for a positive integer $n$, we have $a^{-n} = e$. Then multiplying by $a$ on each side, we get $a = a^{-n+1}$. Then we simply have:
$$
a^n = (a^{-n+1})^n = a^{-n^2+n} = a^{-n(n-1)} = (a^{-n})^{n-1} = e^{n-1} = e
$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just take inverses on both sides of $a^{-n}=e$? Also, you are assuming $a^{-n}=e$, but in your third equality you seem to be using $a^n=e$, which needs justification, as that is supposed to be what you are trying to establish.

Comment: Thank you both for replying and helping me the best way you can. I was also confused why $a^{n}=e$ was used. So can I just say that if $n$ is a positive integer such that $a^{-n}=e$, then by inverses, $a^{n}a^{-n}=a^{n}e$ or $e=a^{n}$ which is a contradiction?

Comment: @numericalorange: Are you addressing me, or Sambo? Multiplying both sides of $a^{-n}=e$ by $a^n$ also gives that if $a^{-n}=e$, then $a^n=e$, yes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're absolutely right; I messed up. I'll edit it now. Bernard's answer above is indeed a much quicker solution.